# How to fetch case insensitive, alphanumeric email from mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, criteria

For example, I need to search 'abc-def+1@email.com'. Now the email input is case sensitive from the user and it should match to 'Abc-Def+1@gmail.com'
I tried using regex, but it is not working in the case of + and - signs in between.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`+` and `.` are special characters in regular expressions and need to be escaped to behave how you're expecting.

If your regular expression is `/abc-def+1@gmail.com/i` then it will match up to `Abc-Def` then fail on the `+`. In regular expressions, `+` means to match `1 or more` of the previous character. So in this case it is looking for at least one `f` then a `1`. To prevent this you would put a `\` in front of the `+` like so: `/abc-def\+1@gmail.com/i`.

The `.` character will match any character, and might give you different results than you want. If we take the previous regular expression, `/abc-def\+1@gmail.com/i` you can see `.` hasn't been escaped. This means that it could match a string like `abc-def+1@gmailgcom`. Just like before, this would need to be escaped, resulting in a regular expression like this: `/abc-def\+1@gmail\.com/i`.

It seems like you're taking in user input for this query, so you'll need to escape any special characters present before querying the database.